# Including a List<SpecificType> in a model, and how to populate it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I currently have three Model classes:

```
public class MarketReport
{
    public MarketReportAbbrStores LISTOFSTORESUMMARY {get; set;}

}

public class MarketReportAbbrStores : List<AbbrStore>
{
    public AbbrStore abbrStore  { get; set; }
}

    public class AbbrStore
{
    public string StoreName { get; set; }
    public int MemberCount { get; set; }
    public int LeaderCount { get; set; }
    public int ActivistCount { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I have no idea if I am doing the above correctly, but I want to populate the list within the MarketReport

```
        foreach (var store in stores)            
        {

            AbbrStore abbrstore = new AbbrStore();
            abbrstore.StoreName = store;
            marketInformation.LISTOFSTORESUMMARY.Add(abbrstore);
            //ERROR: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things wrong here:

1. Your `Leaders` type is a `List` of itself - this shouldn't be a collection type because it's describing a single entity, so just `Leader`
2. `leaderlist` should use PascalCase - `Leaders`
3. `leaderlist` is an instance property, so you would need to instantiate a `MarketReport` to start to populate that list
4. `leaderlist` should be a `List<Leader>` if you don't have a collection type defined (see 1)
5. `List<T>` has an `Add` method which you should use to add new instances of `Leader`
6. You will need to instantiate a new list and assign it to the `Leaders` property before you can start adding to it

Suggested changes:

```
public class Leader
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Precinct { get; set; }
}

public class MarketReport
{
   public List<Leader> Leaders { get; set }
}

this.Leaders = new List<Leader>();
foreach (var store in stores)
{
    var leader = new Leader { ... };
    this.Leaders.Add(leader);
}
```

Comment: 'class Leaders : List<Leader>
    {
        public Leader leader { get; set; }
    }'

Comment: @RaySülzer if you want custom collection of leaders, then only inherit from list parametrized by Leader: `class Leaders : List<Leader> { }`